# How to detect scroll event and direction in a not scrollable element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, scroll, overflow

I am trying to simulate Terminal scroll behavior, which just immediately move the view by 3 lines, without smooth scrolling animation.

Here is my simplified CSS and HTML structure:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
section {
  width: 100%;
}
section#tabs {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}
section#main {
  margin: 15px 0;
}
section#controls {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}
section#imgView {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <article>
      <div data-reactroot>
        <section id="tabs">
          <span>[abc]</span>
          <span>[bcd]</span>
          <span>[cde]</span>
          <span>[def]</span>
          <span>[efg]</span>
        </section>
        <section id="main">
          <div>some texts that is long enough to make this snippet properly represent some shape I want to show</div>
          <div>some texts that is long enough to make this snippet properly represent some shape I want to show</div>
          <div>some texts that is long enough to make this snippet properly represent some shape I want to show</div>
          <div>some texts that is long enough to make this snippet properly represent some shape I want to show</div>
          <div>some texts that is long enough to make this snippet properly represent some shape I want to show</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>some texts that is long enough to make this snippet properly represent some shape I want to show</div>
          <div>some texts that is long enough to make this snippet properly represent some shape I want to show</div>
          <div>some texts that is long enough to make this snippet properly represent some shape I want to show</div>
          <div>some texts that is long enough to make this snippet properly represent some shape I want to show</div>
          <div>some texts that is long enough to make this snippet properly represent some shape I want to show</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
        </section>
        <section id="controls">
          <div>This will always be at the bottom.</div>
        </section>
        <section id="imgView">
          <div>You're not supposed to see this sentence.</div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

The section `tabs` and `controls` will be sticking to their respective edges in the browser, and `imgView` will not be visible unless some code calls it by changing its position related properties.

I made it so body has `overflow: hidden;`, I can't use methods of comparing current scroll position with previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this site](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/) explaining about `mousewheel` or `DOMMouseScroll` event.

An example on that site is an image container zooms in and out when you scroll on the container. So I took the example and let it scroll the body element below.

```js
var body = document.body;

var MouseWheelHandler = function(e) {
  // these codes make it so `delta` return 1 for up and -1 for down in any browser exclude Safari.
  var e = window.event || e;
  var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
  
  // to cancel the normal scrolling behavior
  e.preventDefault();
  
  if(delta===-1) { body.scrollTop += 45; }
  if(delta===1) { body.scrollTop -= 45; }
  
  // this is meant to cancel the normal scrolling behavior. Doesn't work here...
  return false;
}

if (body.addEventListener) {
  // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
  body.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
  // Firefox
  body.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false);
  // IE 6~8
} else body.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler);
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
section {
  width: 100%;
}
section#tabs {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}
section#main {
  margin: 15px 0;
}
section#controls {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}
section#imgView {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <article>
      <div data-reactroot>
        <section id="tabs">
          <span>[abc]</span>
          <span>[bcd]</span>
          <span>[cde]</span>
          <span>[def]</span>
          <span>[efg]</span>
        </section>
        <section id="main">
          <div>some texts that is long enough to make this snippet properly represent some shape I want to show</div>
          <div>some texts that is long enough to make this snippet properly represent some shape I want to show</div>
          <div>some texts that is long enough to make this snippet properly represent some shape I want to show</div>
          <div>some texts that is long enough to make this snippet properly represent some shape I want to show</div>
          <div>some texts that is long enough to make this snippet properly represent some shape I want to show</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>some texts that is long enough to make this snippet properly represent some shape I want to show</div>
          <div>some texts that is long enough to make this snippet properly represent some shape I want to show</div>
          <div>some texts that is long enough to make this snippet properly represent some shape I want to show</div>
          <div>some texts that is long enough to make this snippet properly represent some shape I want to show</div>
          <div>some texts that is long enough to make this snippet properly represent some shape I want to show</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
          <div>another texts to tell the difference on the height</div>
        </section>
        <section id="controls">
          <div>This will always be at the bottom.</div>
        </section>
        <section id="imgView">
          <div>You're not supposed to see this sentence.</div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just listen for the scroll event and then scroll 3 lines up or down.

```
var lineHeight = 18;
var scrollStep = lineHeight * 3;
var lastScrollY = 0;
var scrollContainer = document.querySelector("#main");

scrollContainer.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    if (scrollContainer.scrollTop > lastScrollY) {
        scrollContainer.scrollTop = lastScrollY + scrollStep;
    } else if (scrollContainer.scrollTop < lastScrollY) {
        scrollContainer.scrollTop = lastScrollY - scrollStep;  
    }

    lastScrollY = scrollContainer.scrollTop;
});
```

Comment: How can i implement this as `window.scrollY` won't change in my case?

Comment: I adjusted the answer, I hope that helps